# Button CSS Query

Tags: php, html, css

I have a page that lists 3 buttons, outputted by a PHP if statement, each wrapped in a separate "a" tag. My problem is, when i update the CSS, the width of the buttons change, but the height will not.

I'm seriously baffled, I've checked all other id's and classes to check for conflicts etc, but cannot see anything obvious. The width alters when changed within the developer tools on chrome, but the height will not.

I may be missing something obvious, as i tend to do that, but cannot for the life in me see the issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Code: (Note: I am using an "admin" account, so $admin = 1.)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
session_start();

if($_SESSION['login'] == 0) {
    header('Location: /includes/session_expired.php');
}

$admin = $_COOKIE['admin'];

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheet/main_stylesheet.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/date_time.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <?php
    if($admin == 0) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/success_timer.js"></script>';
    }
    ?>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/divunk/html5.js"></script><![endif]-->
</head>
<body id="nauthBody">
    <div id="nauth-container">
        <div id="nauth-inner-container">
            <div id="nauth-content">
                <?php
                    if($admin == 0) {
                        echo '  <p>You are not authorised to view this page.</p>
                                <span id="timer"></span>';
                    } elseif ($admin == 1) {
                        echo '  <p>Please select an element to manage:</p>
                                <div id="system_selection">
                                    <a href="user_management.php"><input class="system_button" type="button" name="users" value="Users"/></a>
                                    <a href="authorised_devices.php"><input class="system_button" type="button" name="authorised_comps" value="Authorised Computers"/></a>
                                    <a href="resource_management.php"><input class="system_button" type="button" name="resource_management" value="Resource Management"/></a>
                                </div>';
                    }   
                ?>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And CSS:

```
.system_button {
    height: 35px;
    width: 65%; 
}

#system_selection a {
    cursor: pointer;
}

#system_selection {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: I've tried to change the `height: 35px;` to something bigger, and the height of the buttons changed appropriately. Is this what you want? Also make a CTRL+F5 in order to force a cache refresh. It will force the browser to reload the updated .css file, not the cached one.

Comment: You may have to `display: block;` your buttons in order for them to respond to your height styles.

Comment: @SuperJer buttons default to `inline-block`, which works just fine. I also tried it and it worked fine for me, Scott there has to be something else you aren't telling us. What browser are you using?

Comment: `display: block;` Didn't work, neither did a cache refresh. Going to try and re-write the page to try and resolve, hopefully whatever is wrong with the code, won't be replicated.

Comment: In general I would agree with @Kyle, try with another browser and see if it works

Comment: It's possible that `display` was overridden in the CSS somewhere, which is why I suggested it.  If this is the case, it may also be necessary to add `!important` to the style.

Comment: Using Chrome on Mac OSX, I'm just in the process of changing all the ID's etc for all the elements, going to see if there is any conflicts, pretty sure there isn't, but you never know!

Comment: Why do you have `input`s inside of `a`s? That seems like a bad idea.

Comment: See my answer below, that how i found resolution. I'm not sure how I can give you credit @divinecomedian, but it was your input that made me realise. Thanks!

Comment: @ScottThornton Don't worry about it! I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I altered the code to the below. This was inspired by @divinecomedian's comment above, made me realise I could use a form wrapped around each button and change it a Submit input.

Problem solved.

Code: (From inside the "nauth-content" div)

```
        <?php
            if($admin == 0) {
                echo '  <p>You are not authorised to view this page.</p>
                        <span id="timer"></span>';
            } elseif ($admin == 1) {
                echo '  <p>Please select an element to manage:</p>
                        <div id="system_selection">
                            <form action="user_management.php" method="post">
                                <input class="system_button" type="submit" name="users" value="Users"/>
                            </form>
                            <form action="authorised_devices.php" method="post">
                                <input class="system_button" type="submit" name="authorised_comps" value="Authorised Computers"/>
                            </form>
                            <form action="resource_management.php" method="post">
                                <input class="system_button" type="submit" name="resource_management" value="Resource Management"/>
                            </form>
                        </div>';
            }   
        ?>
```

Thanks to everyone that had some input!

Answer (score 0):

right click on your button, use inspect element to find the style on this button. You will find which style has effect on it.